# What is the correct way to think about volatility - in raw terms or logs?

Tags: volatility

I'm thinking about the relationship between the volatility of a bunch of single stocks and the US VIX - as the companies in question tend to export heavily to the US.

To get a grasp over the beta involved, I was thinking about taking 5-day changes in the single stock implied vols (interpolated to a constant maturity like the VIX), 5-day changes in the VIX, and regressing the former on the latter.

But should I be taking log-changes instead?

Comment: Log-change of implied volatility and of VIX?